# Is there anyway to include libc.so in a Lazarus/Free pascal compiled binary?

Tags: glibc, lazarus, freepascal, libc

Is there anyway to include the libc library in a Lazarus or Free Pascal compiled binary? I don't want to use shared libraries because if I compile my application with a newer version of Libc, for example, it will not work on older Linux.

I want this because the following error is shown in the terminal when I run my application in older Linux versions:

> ./app: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by
>   ./app)

Thanks.

Comment: The simple answer is no.

Comment: Have you tried -Xt compile option?     "-Xt Link with static libraries (-static is passed to linker) "

Comment: The simple answer is no, unless you plan to research it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to include the libc library in a Lazarus or Free Pascal compiled binary?

If the compiler supports `-static` flag, and does not require use of dynamic libraries, then your binary will include a copy of (used parts of) `libc.a`

[Documentation](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.0.2/user/userap1.html) suggest that adding `-Xt` to the link line will do that.

> I don't want to use shared libraries because if I compile my application with a newer version of Libc, for example, it will not work on older Linux.

This (compiling on newer, running on older) is generally not supported. Using fully-static binary *may* work, but often fails for other mysterious reasons.

Your best bet is to build on the oldest OS you plan to support, using either a `chroot`-ed build environment, or inside a VM.

Comment: libc is special, calls to libc ini/finalization may need to be fixed in the startup code too if you want to link it static.